# How to fix "ng build --prod --deploy-url="/wp-content/themes/{name_theme}/dist/" - It dosen't work properly

Tags: angular, wordpress, wamp

I create template Angular 7 on Wordpress. Locally(http://localhost:4200) everthing it's fine but when I'll make ng build --prod --deploy-url="/wp-content/themes/{theme_name}/dist/ It doesn't work properly. The themes shall be started and it seems to be well but when I click in menu that site refreshed. I don't know why. My english isn't so good. Please calm down.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the `output path` option

ng build --output-path=wp-content/themes/{theme_name}/dist/ --prod"